# How to simulate a request from view.

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new in cakephp and I'm just wondering, how to test models and controllers without using views?

I have to simulate saving data using models and controllers without using froms from views. I was thinking about to make an array with the needed values, but maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can mock your model functions using code like:

```
$model = $this->getMockForModel('MyModel', array('save'));
$model->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output variables at any time from controllers (or models) without getting to the views. Yes, it's not how you should do things with an MVC framework, but for testing, it's pretty easy to whack this below your database call in the model/controller:

```
<? echo '<pre>'; print_r($my_array); exit; ?>
```

The other thing you can do is at the top of your action function in the controller put:

```
$this->layout = '';
$this->render(false);
```

... which will bypass the layout and skip the view rendering, so you can output whatever you like within that function without using the view.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your action, you may use:

> $this->autoRender = false;

This will allow you to access your action directly by going to it's path (*e.g.* CONTROLLER/ACTION). Before passing your data array to save() or saveAll(), I recommend double-checking it with Debugger::dump(), and follow that with die(). This will make the array containing the save data print on your screen so you can verify it looks proper and follows Cake's conventions. The die() will prevent it from actually saving the data.

If everything looks correct, remove the dump() and die() and test it out again.

The first response, from Ayo Akinyemi, should also work well if you are Unit Testing your application.